# How to assign subsequent bits to C enumeration members?

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

Here's what I got:

```c
enum X {
    NONE = 0x00000000,
    FLAG_1 = 0x00000001,
    FLAG_2 = 0x00000002,
    FLAG_3 = 0x00000004,
    FLAG_4 = 0x00000008,
    FLAG_5 = 0x00000010,
    // ...
    FLAG_32 = 0x80000000
}
```

Is there a way to make "bit numbering" automatic so I could like insert a flag so all that goes next get "renumbered"?

I'm just designing an API and I want to keep related flags together, ordered in a specific sequence. The problem is when I add something that goes in the middle I have to manually reassign all numbering that goes after the inserted item. Let's say in my example I want to add FLAG_2A = 0x00000004, and FLAG_3 should be 0x00000008 and so on. Is there a "full auto" way of doing it?

OK, here's the first thing that comes to mind:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum { __FLAGS1_BASE = __COUNTER__ };
#define __FLAGS1_CT 1 << (__COUNTER__ - __FLAGS1_BASE - 1)

typedef enum __TEST1 {
    FLAG1_0 = 0,
    FLAG1_1 = __FLAGS1_CT,
    FLAG1_2 = __FLAGS1_CT,
    FLAG1_3 = __FLAGS1_CT,
    FLAG1_4 = __FLAGS1_CT
} TEST1;

enum { __FLAGS2_BASE = __COUNTER__ };
#define __FLAGS2_CT 1 << (__COUNTER__ - __FLAGS2_BASE - 1)

typedef enum __TEST2 {
    FLAG2_0 = 0,
    FLAG2_1 = __FLAGS2_CT,
    FLAG2_2 = __FLAGS2_CT,
    FLAG2_3 = __FLAGS2_CT,
    FLAG2_4 = __FLAGS2_CT
} TEST2;

int main() {
    printf("X = %u\n", FLAG2_3); // should output 4.
    return 0;
}
```

Is it the only way, or is there something simpler than that?

Comment: IMO the best way is to assign the values manually. At least that's readable.

Comment: Your solution is as good as it gets without generating boilerplate macros. You could achieve slightly better syntax with Boost.Preprocessor (e.g. `MAKE_FLAGS(MyEnum, flag1, flag2, flag3)`), since they already have the needed boilerplate.

Comment: Please note that enumeration constants shouldn't be used for bit masks/bit fields in the first place, since they are by definition `int` and signed, and therefore unsuitable to use in bitwise arithmetic.

Comment: @Lundin As long as I don't place a negative int on the right side of a bit shift operator it should work, right? All except bit shifting seems to be well defined.

Comment: @Harry Left shifting data into the sign bit is undefined behavior. Left shifting a negative number is undefined behavior. Right shifting a negative number is platform-specific. And so on.

Comment: If the names can be generated, you can probably generate the macros too.  In my experience, the names are more diverse — OPEN_SET, CLOSE_SET, READ_ENABLED, WRITE_ENABLED, EXEC_PROHIBITED, etc — and that makes it much harder to generate the values.  You have to list the names somehow; ensuring that the values are a packed set of bit values is harder.

Answer (score 4):

I threw together a quick implementation of the `MAKE_FLAGS` macro HolyBlackCat suggested:

```
#define E3(...) E2(E2(E2(E2(E2(E2(E2(__VA_ARGS__)))))))
#define E2(...) E1(E1(E1(E1(E1(E1(E1(E1(__VA_ARGS__))))))))
#define E1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define EMPTY()
#define TUPLE_AT_2(x,y,...) y

#define CHECK(...) TUPLE_AT_2(__VA_ARGS__,0,)
#define EQ_END_END ,1

#define CAT(a,b) CAT_(a,b)
#define CAT_(a,b) a##b

#define LOOP_() LOOP
#define LOOP(x,y,...) CAT(LOOP, CHECK(EQ_END_##y))(x,y,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOOP1(x,...) 
#define LOOP0(x,y,...) y = x << 1, LOOP_ EMPTY() ()(y,__VA_ARGS__)

#define HEAD(x,...) x
#define MAKE_FLAGS(name,...) typedef enum { HEAD(__VA_ARGS__,) = 1, E3(LOOP(__VA_ARGS__, END)) } name 

MAKE_FLAGS(MyEnum, flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4);
// expands to:
// typedef enum { flag1 = 1, flag2 = flag1 << 1, flag3 = flag2 << 1, flag4 = flag3 << 1, } MyEnum;
```

Comment: Nice! Could remove a few repetitions of `E1` since we know the exact max limit (64 iterations).

Comment: I think it should work with up to 66 iterations now, that's as close as I got to 64 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
enum X_bits {
    B0,  // replace Bx with actual flag name
    B1,
    B2,
    //...
    B32
};

#define FLAG(x)  FLAG_##x = 1U << x
enum X {
    NONE = 0,
    FLAG(B0),  // will define FLAG_B0 with the appropriate value 0x1
    FLAG(B1),
    FLAG(B2),
    //...
    FLAG(B32)
};
```

Actual bit numbers and bit marks are computed automatically.

Comment: Why is it better to type out enum constants manually than integer constants though?

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as @chqrlie's answer (using a second enum to generate sequental indices), but generated with a macro:

```
#define MAKE_FLAGS(name_, zero_, seq_) \
    enum CAT(BitIndices_, name_) { END( IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_a seq_ ) }; \
    typedef enum name_ { zero_ = 0, END( IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_a seq_ ) } name_;

#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_end

#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_a(name_) CAT(bitindex_, name_), IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_b
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_b(name_) CAT(bitindex_, name_), IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_a
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_a_end
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop1_b_end

#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_a(name_) name_ = 1ull << CAT(bitindex_, name_), IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_b
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_b(name_) name_ = 1ull << CAT(bitindex_, name_), IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_a
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_a_end
#define IMPL_MAKE_FLAGS_loop2_b_end
```

Then `MAKE_FLAGS( E, none, (x)(y)(z) )` expands to:

```
enum BitIndices_E { bitindex_x, bitindex_y, bitindex_z, };
typedef enum E
{
    none = 0,
    x = 1ull << bitindex_x,
    y = 1ull << bitindex_y,
    z = 1ull << bitindex_z,
} E;
```

Comment: Cool, just a quick heads up: I think it's unspecified behavior whether sequence iteration works, see  6.10.3.4p4 and Annex J "When a fully expanded macro...". (although I don't know of any otherwise standard confirming preprocessors, where it doesn't work)

Comment: @camel-cdr Good to know, I gave up trying to understand the standard-mandated preprocessor behavior. :S

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to type it out manually, it's just 32 rows.

In case you insist on generating it with macros, then the least bad version is *not* to run amok with some "clever" contrived ones, but to go with a de facto standard solution using "x-macros":

```
#define FLAG_LIST(X) \
  X(1) X(2) X(3) X(4)  /* ... */

#define flag_decl(val) FLAG_##val = val,
#define flag_mask_decl(val) FLAG_MASK_##val = 1u << (val-1),

typedef enum 
{
  FLAG_0 = 0,
  FLAG_LIST(flag_decl)
} flag;

typedef enum 
{
  FLAG_MASK_0 = 0,
  FLAG_LIST(flag_mask_decl)
} flag_mask;
```

Pre-processor output of the above:

```
typedef enum
{
  FLAG_0 = 0,
  FLAG_1 = 1, FLAG_2 = 2, FLAG_3 = 3, FLAG_4 = 4,
} flag;

typedef enum
{
  FLAG_MASK_0 = 0,
  FLAG_MASK_1 = 1u << (1 -1), FLAG_MASK_2 = 1u << (2 -1), FLAG_MASK_3 = 1u << (3 -1), FLAG_MASK_4 = 1u << (4 -1),
} flag_mask;
```

Comment: This only works for numbered flags, tough. I think the question only used `FLAG_0,FLAG_1,..` as examples.

Comment: @camel-cdr This can be very easily tweaked to whatever format that's required.

Answer (score 0):

My last take: flags.h header:

```c
#pragma once

#define BIT_FLAG_BASE(base) enum { base = __COUNTER__ + 1 } ///< Sets the base for the bit flag counter.
#define BIT_FLAG(base) 1U << (__COUNTER__ - base) ///< Gets the next bit for the bit flag counter.
```

Used like this:

```c
#include "flags.h"

BIT_FLAG_BASE(MyFlag);

enum MyFlags {
    B1 = BIT_FLAG(MyFlag),
    B2 = BIT_FLAG(MyFlag),
    // ...
    B31 = BIT_FLAG(MyFlag)
};
```

Comment: [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**](https://www.port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know. But it's STM32 HAL coding style used all over. I just copy it. I mean HAL provides it's drivers, I add my custom drivers and I try to emulate the style of the code around it. IDK if it's correct, I've read somewhere when you expand a code base it's good to emulate its coding style. I'm quite confused about it. C is probably doomed to look a bit messy I guess.

Comment: `__COUNTER__` is also a compiler extension. You could do `#line 0` and use `__LINE__` instead, but that would mess up the line numbers in compiler warnings and only work if every flag is written on a separate line.

Comment: @Harry *But it's STM32 HAL coding style...*  Just because **someone else** improperly uses reserved identifiers is no reason to do it yourself.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You've convinced me, I've changed it in my code. Also changed the macros names to BIT_FLAG_BASE(base) and BIT_FLAG(base) to make it more apparent what they do.

Answer (score 0):

How many combinations are there? I am a verbose guy, I would do:

```
// for i in $(seq 3); do echo "#define BITFLAG_$i(N$(printf ",_%s" $(seq $i))) \\"$'\n'"enum N { \\$(seq $((i-1)) | xargs -i printf "\n\t_{} = (1 << {}), \\\\")"$'\n'"};"; done
#define BITFLAG_1(N,_1) \
enum N { \
};
#define BITFLAG_2(N,_1,_2) \
enum N { \
        _1 = (1 << 1), \
};
#define BITFLAG_3(N,_1,_2,_3) \
enum N { \
        _1 = (1 << 1), \
        _2 = (1 << 2), \
};
/* etc. */
    
#define BITFLAG_N(_10,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,_0,N,...)  BITFLAG_##N
#define BITFLAG(...)  BITFLAG_N(__VA_ARGS__,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

BITFLAG(
    X,
    FLAG1,
    FLAG2,
)
```